# KDE: suspend to 'freeze' state instead of 'mem'

Tags: kde, power-management, suspend

I have a Lenovo Helix 2, which has busted suspend-to-RAM (S3) support. "Light sleep" mode (S0ix), however, works fine, as tested with `echo freeze > /sys/power/state`.

I can bind the power button to use `freeze` instead of `mem` using `acpid` event handlers, but what I really want to do is get the desktop environment to handle this, since it can do things like "suspend after N minutes of user inactivity" that `acpid` can't.

Unfortunately, the only options the KDE power manager gives me are "Do Nothing", "Lock Screen", "Suspend", "Hibernate", and "Power Off". It has a "run script" option, but that only applies when transitioning between power states -- e.g. I could have it run a script when going from AC to battery, or from battery to low battery, but not when on battery power and idle for 30 minutes.

So, is there some way -- either as part of KDE configuration, or as a systemd or sysfs or kernel option -- to override things so that it will try to `freeze` instead of, or as an alternative to, `suspend`ing?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of acpi events you may be able to look into 
`/etc/default/acpi-support` (on latest ubuntu).  However, I'm not sure this would work well with your desktop or not.  It is possible to specify acpi-sleep method there if you switch to the acpi-support suspend management.